# Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster

Tags: machine-learning

## Define function to extract titles from passenger names

```
def get_title(name):
    title_search = re.search(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', name)
    # If the title exists, extract and return it.
    if title_search:
        return title_search.group(1)
    return ""
```

`title_search = re.search(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', name)` What does this mean?

Comment: Post the code in code format

Answer (score 0):

The titanic dataset has names of the passenger like: `Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith` and `Behr, Mr. Karl Howell`

The titles here are `Mr.` and `Miss.`

```
title_search = re.search(' ([A-Za-z]+).', name)
```

The above line of code searches for names having titles. ***Mr. and Miss.*** are not the only ones, it could also be for example, ***Dr., Prof.*** and so on. Since we do not know before hand what are the titles but we know the pattern, which is **'alphabets followed by a period'**, we look for those words alone.

`([A-Za-z]+).` means, look for any word that starts with A-Z or a-z and end with a fullstop.

I suggest you read about regular expressions.